# CSS/HTML image swap not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image swap but it is not working. `gpu.jpg` is showing and dissapering when I hover over it, but it flickers invisible and visible. But `gpu_replace.jpg` does not display at all, what am I doing wrong? bellow is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="contents">
    <h2><center>What are the components of a graphics card and what do they do?</h2>
    <h3><center>Bellow a GTX 980 PCB.</h3>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 100px;">
        <img src="pic\980_pcb.jpg" style="width:908.2px;height:398.05px position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
        <span class="imgswap">
            <img src="pic\gpu.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 115px; left: 273.5px;"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span.imgswap {
    background-image: url("pic/gpu_replace.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat; display:block;
}
span.imgswap:hover img {visibility:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might help you.

### HTML

```
<span class="imgswap"> </span>
```

### CSS

```
span.imgswap{
 background: url(http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/4021429.png) no-repeat;
 height: 58px;
 width: 208px;
 display: block;
}
span.imgswap:hover{
 background: url(http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/4021429.png?theme=hotdog) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had do do some changes: `span.imgswap {
  background-image: url("pic/gpu_replace.jpg") no-repeat ;
  height: 167px;
  width: 163px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 115px;
  left: 273.5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  display:block;}`

Comment: But you need to add :hover class and change background images

Comment: I changed the images, and did some other stuff, cant remember what.. But it works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`span` by default is not block element, so in your code `span.imgswap` has a computed height of **0**. This is why you can't see "gpu_replace.jpg", even though it has a visible child!

When you hover "gpu.jpg", its parent node `span.imgswap` is also hovered, so `span.imgswap:hover img {visibility:hidden;}` makes "gpu.jpg" invisible, and then... it's invisible so it's not hovered --> its parent is not hovered --> `span.imgswap:hover img {visibility:hidden;}` is not applied --> "gpu.jpg" apprears again --> .... That's why "gpu.jpg" flashes.